# Multiplying a string k*horizontally and v*times vertically

Tags: string, scala, multiplication

Problem:

You are given a string of n lines, each substring being n characters long. For example:

```
s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
```

A k-horizontal scaling of a string consists of replicating k times each character of the string (except `'\n'`).

A v-vertical scaling of a string consists of replicating v times each part of the squared string.

Function `scale(strng, k, v)` will perform a k-horizontal scaling and a v-vertical scaling.

Example:

```
a = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
scale(a, 2, 3) --> "aabbccdd\naabbccdd\naabbccdd\neeffgghh\neeffgghh\neeffgghh\niijjkkll\niijjkkll\niijjkkll\nmmnnoopp\nmmnnoopp\nmmnnoopp".
```

My problem is that I've already written the function and for my liking it is completely correct.

But when I try and run the program through the tests, there a single bug, thanks to which my program doesn't pass any of them.

I attached the tests to to the bottom of the question, please help.

```
object Kata {

    def scale(xs: String, k: Int, n: Int): String ={
      if(xs=="")
        ""
      else
      xs.split("\n")
   .map(_.map(_.toString*k).mkString("","","\n") * n)
   .mkString
      }



}
```

```
> Test Results:
 KataTest
 scale(abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop, 2, 3) should return aabbccdd\naabbccdd\naabbccdd\neeffgghh\neeffgghh\neeffgghh\niijjkkll\niijjkkll\niijjkkll\nmmnnoopp\nmmnnoopp\nmmnnoopp
Test Failed

>"...pp
mmnnoopp
mmnnoopp[
]" was not equal to "...pp
mmnnoopp
mmnnoopp[]"
 Stack Trace
Completed in 24ms
 scale(, 5, 5) should return
 scale(Kj\nSH, 1, 2) should return Kj\nKj\nSH\nSH
Test Failed

>"Kj
Kj
SH
SH[
]" was not equal to "Kj
Kj
SH
SH[]"
 Stack Trace
 scale(lxnT\nqiut\nZZll\nFElq, 1, 2) should return lxnT\nlxnT\nqiut\nqiut\nZZll\nZZll\nFElq\nFElq
Test Failed

>"...
ZZll
ZZll
FElq
FElq[
]" was not equal to "...
ZZll
ZZll
FElq
FElq[]"
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 scale(YVjosW\nHGhKGZ\nLHNMLm\nJtcWCj\ngVtjyk\nOJBkOK, 2, 2) should return YYVVjjoossWW\nYYVVjjoossWW\nHHGGhhKKGGZZ\nHHGGhhKKGGZZ\nLLHHNNMMLLmm\nLLHHNNMMLLmm\nJJttccWWCCjj\nJJttccWWCCjj\nggVVttjjyykk\nggVVttjjyykk\nOOJJBBkkOOKK\nOOJJBBkkOOKK
Test Failed

>"...BkkOOKK
OOJJBBkkOOKK[
]" was not equal to "...BkkOOKK
OOJJBBkkOOKK[]"
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First replica each letter of the line by `k` times and then replicate each line by `v` times.

```
@ 
def scale(xs: String, k: Int, n: Int): String = xs.split("\n").flatMap(line => Array.fill(n)(line.flatMap(char => s"$char" * k))).mkString("\n") 
defined function scale

@ scale("abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop", 2, 3) 
res11: String = """aabbccdd
aabbccdd
aabbccdd
eeffgghh
eeffgghh
eeffgghh
iijjkkll
iijjkkll
iijjkkll
mmnnoopp
mmnnoopp
mmnnoopp"""
```

Summary:

```
 def scale(xs: String, k: Int, n: Int): String = xs
 .split("\n")
 .flatMap { line =>
   val repeatKTimes = line.flatMap(char => s"$char" * k) // each char is repeated k times
   Array.fill(n)(repeatKTimes)
 }.mkString("\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

When building big strings, I would recommend using a [**StringBuilder**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.html) to avoid extra garbage created with normal string concatenation.

```
def scale(string: String, k: Int, v: Int): String = {
  import scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder

  val textBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity = string.length * k * v)
  val lineBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity = k * 5)
  // The five above is just an stimated of how many characters there could be for a line on average.
  // The value does not have to be precise, but if it is just a little bit bigger than the real size, it would be more performant, without too much extra memory.
  // You can play with it.

  string.foreach {
    case '\n' =>
      val line = lineBuilder.append('\n').result()
      lineBuilder.clear()
      (0 until v).foreach { _ =>
        textBuilder.append(line)
      }

    case char =>
      (0 until k).foreach { _ =>
        lineBuilder.append(char)
      }
  }

  textBuilder.result()
}

scale("abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop", 2, 3) 
res: String =
"""
aabbccdd
aabbccdd
aabbccdd
eeffgghh
eeffgghh
eeffgghh
iijjkkll
iijjkkll
iijjkkll
mmnnoopp
mmnnoopp
mmnnoopp
"""
```

Note: Pamu's answer also uses **StringBuilders** under the hood, both `*` and `mkString` are implemented in terms of them, thus both answers should perform more or less similar. Mine was just an attempt to avoid intermediate **Arrays** *(but it uses intermediate StringBuilders)*.